# Как сделать правильный порядок загрузки скриптов

Tags: ajax

Добрый день!

Есть простая страница с ajax загрузкой, на которой использую библиотеку **masonry** для построения сетки с блоками.

Если добавить все блоки вручную они выстраиваются как нужно.

```
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px;"></div>
```

Если их добавлять **append**'ом через **ajax** то к ним не применяются нужные свойства свойства.

```
<div class="item"></div>
```

Порядок загрузки скриптов

```
<script src="template/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="template/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="template/ajax.js"></script>
```

Проблема не только с этой библиотекой, я в целом не могу понять как правильно реализовать загрузку скриптов. Данный случай для был приведен для примера. Объясните пожалуйста как правильно подгружать данные **ajax**'ом или подгружать остальные библиотеки что бы они работали корректно при каждой подгрузке данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы делаете что-то типа

```
jQuery('.class').startManipulationOnEvent();
```

jQuery и большинство других библиотек не начинают следить за элементами **.class** и, соответственно, срабатывание событий на них. Они делают **текущую выборку** элементов .class и вешают на них обработчики (или меняют им стили, или еще что-то), поэтому на новые элементы (созданные после window.onload, например, появившиеся в результате аякс-запросов) заданные правила не распространяются.

Решения тут может быть три:

1. Подключать библиотеки после формирования HTML
2. Если библиотека своя, то регулярно обновлять в ней список элементов по коллбэку
3. Если библиотека чужая, то подобный коллбэк может быть описан в документации
4. Иногда можно снять все обработчики и повесить заново (опять зависит от библиотеки), но это некошерный путь.